# Is it possible to pass subscription specific parameters to API called?

Tags: subscription, azure-api-management

I am using Azure API Management.
I have create an API, a product and a subscription

The API is generic. it does a lookup of sales order history and requires a customer id to show that customers orders onyl. The relation between customer and subscription is intended as 1:1.
However I dont want subscribers to see other subscribers data. I thought, I could set a fixed parameter (e.g. customer id) to each subscription to be passed to the API on any call.

Or how can limit API to be only show subscriber specific data? Somehow the API has to differentiate between subscriber. Any idea?

Comment: When subscribers call your API, don't they pass in the customer id as part of the request?

Comment: No, they should not. This could lead to one customer looking up data from another. For example prices or addresses

Answer (score 0):

When calling an API using a subscription key, the [`context.Subscription`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions#ref-context-subscription) and [`context.User`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions#ref-context-user) (not for standalone subscriptions) are set for use in policies.

Since you have a 1:1 relation between customer and subscription, you could set a header in the request to the backend with the user's email using the below policy statement in the `inbound` policy section

```xml
<set-header name="x-customer-email" exists-action="override">
  <value>@(context.User.Email)</value>
</set-header>
```

Comment: Is there also a way to get information on the user from aad B2C when using aad B2C to authenticate users?

Comment: You could fetch information from the token directly, if present as a claim or call the [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview) using [send-request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#SendRequest)